# Hyperbolic segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can there be a segment on a hyperbolic plane that goes from point $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$ in the hyperbolic plane. There are some rules, though for this to work:

1) The segment must apply to the rules of segments in hyperbolic space.

2) The segment a length $\gt 0$

3) Only one single point $(0,0)$ that exists on the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the axioms of intermediacy are true on the hyperbolic plane. That is, if for three distinct points $A,B,C$, we say that  $B$ is between $A$ and $C$ then we say that $C$ is not between $A$ and $B$. A segment that starts from $A$ and ends at $A$ will be a circle like configuration on which the intermediacy axioms do not hold. See the illustration below.

[image]

[The axioms of intermediacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_geometry) are the basic axioms of the so called ordered geometries. The hyperbolic plane (space) is a specialization of the ordered plane (space) space.